# Installed Laravel Framework and getting error when i install artisian with (php artisan migrate:install)

Tags: laravel

Installed Laravel Framework and getting Error when I install  artisian with the below (`php artisan migrate:install`)

My PHP version is **[PHP: 5.5.11]**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-testing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php on line 426

E:\xampp\htdocs>cd laravel-testing

E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-testing>php artisan migrate:install

Parse error: **syntax error, unexpected '['** in E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-testing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php on line 426
```

What may be the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does line 426 (and surrounding) of helpers.php say? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: I have added the same error message that copied from Command Prompt

Comment: Is it possible that you have two PHP versions installed? and the one you use to run artisan is older than 5.4? `php -v` to find out

Comment: By the way, [line 426 in helpers.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L426)

Comment: Yes i have two versions installed [PHP: 5.5.11] and [PHP: 5.3.8]. But currently  am using  [PHP: 5.5.11].Yes the same line in helpers.php

Comment: This errors occurs on old php version. I think your system is using the older version. Check your "path" vars. Have you tried `php -v` from your command line ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove older version of your php and set latest version in environment variable. Secondly I would recommend to read [this](http://culttt.com/2013/05/06/laravel-4-migrations/) article. It's definitely going to help you understand migration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have **composer** installed in the VM (Vagrant) if you are not using homestead (laravel specific vagrant dist)

I was getting the same error. Wondering why the PHP version would matter if the VM was using a single and correct PHP dist.

https://getcomposer.org/download/